# How can I validate XML documents in a specific database against a schema in the Schemas database in Marklogic's query console?

Tags: xml, validation, schema, marklogic, marklogic-10

Using Marklogic 10's Query Console. I am trying to validate XML documents against two different schemas that I have loaded into the Schemas database. The XML documents I want to validate are in a database I created called "myDatabase". I want to be able to run validation against existing documents in the database and also run validation before inserting new documents into the database.

I've written two different queries (to validate existing documents and another to run before document creation), but the only way I can get them to work in Query Console is if I select the Documents database, select the App-Services server, and use `xdmp:eval()` to get the documents from "myDatabase".

My question is, how can I run these queries against documents in "myDatabase" without using the `xdmp:eval()` workaround?

I'm including the queries below:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Validate existing documents :)

import schema namespace mods = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" at "/mods-3-7.xsd";
import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";   
declare namespace svrl = "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl";  

let $query := 
  "xquery version '1.0-ml';
  let $doc := fn:doc('/test.xml')
  return $doc"
let $docs := xdmp:eval($query, (),
                <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                  <database>{xdmp:database("myDatabase")}</database>
                </options>)
for $doc in $docs
return 
(
  try { concat(fn:document-uri(validate strict {$doc}), "&#xa;  MODS validation passed") }
  catch ($e) { concat("MODS validation failed: ", $e/error:format-string/text()) },

  schematron:validate($doc, schematron:get("/schematron.sch"))/svrl:schematron-output/svrl:failed-assert/svrl:text/concat("  Schematron error - ", text())
)
```

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Validate new documents before loading :)

import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";   
declare namespace svrl = "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl";  

let $node := xdmp:document-get("temp/test.xml")
let $query := 
  "xquery version '1.0-ml';
  import schema namespace mods = &quot;http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3&quot; at &quot;/mods-3-7.xsd&quot;;
  import module namespace schematron = &quot;http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron&quot; at &quot;/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy&quot;; 
  declare variable $node as node()* external;
  xdmp:document-insert('/test.xml', validate strict {$node} )"
return
  (
    try { 
          xdmp:eval($query, (xs:QName('node'), $node),
            <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
              <database>{xdmp:database("myDatabase")}</database>
            </options>)
        }
    catch ($e) { "Validation failed: ",
                 $e/error:format-string/text() },

    schematron:validate($node, schematron:get("/schematron.sch"))/svrl:schematron-output/svrl:failed-assert/svrl:text/concat("  Schematron error - ", text())
  )
```

**Update:**
If I try to run the validation query or even just try to compile schematron in any database other than Documents I get the following error message:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-NODB: xdmp:eval("declare variable $validator-uri as xs:string external;&#10;decla...", (fn:QName("","validator-uri"), "/schematron.sch-validator.xsl", fn:QName("","validator-xslt"), ...), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>0</database></options>) -- No database with identifier 0
```

Comment: Just a general comment, since you are using MarkLogic 10 - stop using `xdmp:eval()` and start using `xdmp:invoke-function()` https://www.marklogic.com/blog/first-class-functions/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I read through the article you linked to, but it sounds like this is mainly an issue when using Javascript. We write everything with XQuery, so I'm not sure this applies.

Comment: No, it is a best practice to avoid evaluating strings, regardless of the language. Plus, you can avoid having to escape the double quotes in your second example, since the code block was wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: But the only reason you are looking to switch context is because when you select anything other than the Documents database, the code is failing with the XDMP-NODB error? I have seen a database resolved as `0` for the Database ID for AMPS and Triggers when the Security Dababase has been restored from a backup from another system. Is there anything relevant regarding database config changes or restores that could be causing issues? If you have access to MarkLogic Support, you could also file a support ticket and ask for assistance.

Comment: That's right. I am only using xdmp:eval to switch context because the code fails with the XDMP-NODB error if I try to run it against any database other than Documents and the server App-Services. Any other context causes the code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, check if `Schemas` is selected as schemas database for your `myDatabase` documents database.

The app server that you evaluate against dictates which documents and modules database should be used. The documents database in turn dictates which schemas and triggers database go with it. If you create an empty database in Admin UI, it sets schemas and triggers to `(none)` by default. Same might apply to other methods to create a database.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. Schemas is selected as the schemas database for myDatabase. So, I'm pretty stuck.